# is this really such a complicated query or is the server being slow?

Tags: mysql

recently inserted a lot of rows into these tables and now the query times out:

```
SELECT * FROM eng
WHERE english IN (SELECT eng FROM `eng-jap`)
ORDER BY lastmodified DESC
```

table eng-jap has about 25,000 rows, here is some stats on it:

```
Format          dynamic
Collation       utf8_general_ci
Rows            24,960
Row length ø    316
Row size ø      328 B
Next Autoindex  26,468
Type    Usage
Data    7,724.0 KiB
Index   264.0 KiB
Total   7,988.0 KiB
```

and for table eng:

```
Format          dynamic
Collation       utf8_general_ci
Rows            23,691
Row length ø    105
Row size ø      117 B
Next Autoindex  24,771
Type    Usage
Data    2,451.4 KiB
Index   260.0 KiB
Total   2,711.4 KiB
```

just select * from table gets (Query took 0.0002 sec) for either table

i just cant believe a very simple subquery like this with a couple k's in each table needs more than the 160 sec timeout i have set, and then times out...

i hope its like a setting in my tables thats causing it. or mysql really cant do a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's having to cross-reference all the elements from one table with all the elements of the other.

Perhaps this might work better:

```
SELECT `eng`.* FROM `eng`
JOIN `eng-jap` ON `eng`.`english` = `eng-jap`.`eng`
ORDER BY `eng`.`lastmodified` DESC
```

Also make sure you have suitable Indexes defined. This will help speed up the query.

Comment: your query also times out. i had indexing on the tables, though i dropped it to see if that would stop the timing out.  before my recent update (alot of inserts) this query worked lighting fast, never seemed to have any lag time. so it seems strange that all of a sudden with more rows in the table it times out...

Comment: i took a good look and redefined my indexes, and now the search works quickly again. thanks